# groovy immutable object with parent class

Tags: groovy, abstract-class, immutability

I have two immutable groovy classes that have a few shared values that I'm trying to abstract to a parent class. However when I create the following, the second test case always fails. Although everything compiles correctly and no error is thrown at runtime, when I assign the parent property int he constructor, it is never set, resulting in a null value. I havent found any documentation that forbids this, but I'm wondering is this even possible? I've tried a number of configuration of Annotations and  class-types (e.g. removing abstract from the parent) but nothing seems to work short of just removing the `@Immutable` tag altogether.

```
abstract class TestParent {
       String parentProperty1
}

@ToString(includeNames = true)
@Immutable
class TestChild extends TestParent {
   String childProperty1
   String childProperty2
}


class TestCase {
    @Test
    void TestOne() {
        TestChild testChild = new TestChild(
                childProperty1: "childOne",
                childProperty2: "childTwo",
                parentProperty1: "parentOne"
        )

        assert testChild
        assert testChild.parentProperty1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code for the [ImmutableASTTransformation](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/transform/ImmutableASTTransformation.java), the Map-arg constructor added by the `createConstructorMapCommon` method does not include a call to super(args) in the method body.

which means that immutable classes are self contained by default

Now if you want to do it you need to use composition instead of inheritance and this is an example of how you can do it :

```
import groovy.transform.*

@TupleConstructor
class A {
  String a
}

@Immutable(knownImmutableClasses=[A])
class B {
  @Delegate A base
  String b
}

def b = new B(base: new A("a"), b: "b")
assert b.a
```

i hope this will help :)